# Change selected toolbar menu item background color

Tags: android, menu, background

I read a lot of stackoverflow answers about set selected item on NavigationDrawer/View, but I can't get the same behaviour with my toolbar items.

How can I get selected item with different background color?

I can set checked and checkable onOptionItemSelected to get checkboxes but I want to use selection behaviour.

Like navigationView but on toolbar menu items:

[image]

[image]

Comment: provide some screenshots. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Added two screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Create custom view and give it to menu item :

```
    <item android:id="@+id/activity_main_alerts_menu_item"
 android:title="Alerts"
 app:actionLayout="@layout/CUSTOMVIEW" 
<!-- important part --> app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

And accessing it on this event in activity :

```
@Override 
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
final MenuItem alertMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.activity_main_alerts_menu_item);
 FrameLayout rootView = (FrameLayout) alertMenuItem.getActionView(); 
redCircle = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_alert_red_circle);
 countTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_alert_count_textview);
 return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); 
}
```

Read [this article](https://stablekernel.com/using-custom-views-as-menu-items/) for details

Comment: It is not possible to use without custom views? NavigationView use menu and it can have this behaviour.

Comment: @Dahnark no it's impossible to do it like navigationView. maybe you can create right navigationDrawer for your options and open it by action menuitem